# Is "differentially" updating a local Docker image with the latest changes possible?

Tags: docker

This is my first time using Docker, so excuse my potentially improper terminology. Our team uses a Docker image that contains the entire development environment, minus the git repo that needs to be cloned manually within a persistent container based on this image. The Docker image hosted on our repository is frequently updated, e.g. to include new 3rd party dependencies and other files, making my local environment - which includes a directory with the git repo where I do my work - out-of-date.

Is there a way to update my local environment with the latest image changes without having to pull the entire image with `docker pull image:latest` and start from scratch? Assuming there are no conflicts, I would like to preserve my local changes (git repo clone, local filesystem modifications etc.); so I'm looking for something like `git pull` for Docker, if that makes sense.

I must have missed something, but a search on this issue didn't yield any viable solutions.

Comment: Sounds like you want to [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only)

Comment: Agree with @CoryCoolguy, you probably want to mount a local volume(s) that contains your git repo/filesystem changes into your docker container.

Comment: Mounting a volume might as well be the only way here - feel free to make your comment an answer and I will accept it.